# itertools does not work in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

error log:

```
2011-12-05 14:56:01.211

<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'product'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ellipt-test/1.355173855249110456/helloworld.py", line 494, in <module>
    F16 = field_elements(2, 4)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ellipt-test/1.355173855249110456/helloworld.py", line 218, in field_elements
    result = list(itertools.product(*([range(p)]*n)))
```

What's the problem? On my computer, the script works!

Answer (score 8):

The [app engine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html#The_Application_Environment) say:

> Your application can run in one of three runtime environments: […] a choice of Python 2.5 or the experimental Python 2.7.

I'm assuming this implies the default Python is version 2.5.

The [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) docs say:

> New in version 2.6.

I'm not really familiar with GAE, so not sure how you'd switch your app to use 2.7.